# Printing out 2d Array in matrix format java

Tags: java

**How do you print a 2-dimensional array in a fine format?**

I want to print the matrix as seen below, with a max 4 spaces for numbers and max 2 spaces for fractional numbers
eg xxxx.xx

```
 double A[][]= {
    { 3.152 ,96.1 , 77.12},
    { 608.12358 , -5.15412456453 , -36.1},
    { -753..555555,  6000.156564 , -155.541654}
};

//I need this output
   3.15 |   96.10 |   77.12
 608.12 |   -5.15 |  -36.10
-753.55 | 6000.15 | -155.54
```

Comment: Read up about [System.out.printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This might help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double A[][]= {
            { 3.152 ,96.1 , 77.12},
            { 608.12358 , -5.15412456453 , -36.1},
            { -753.555555,  6000.156564 , -155.541654}
        };
    //Number  of characters in format , here XXXX.XX length is 7
    int numberFormatLength=7;
    //Iterating through Array
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++){
            //Calculating number of spaces required.
            int spacesRequired=numberFormatLength-String.format("%.2f",A[i][j]).length();
            //Creating calculated number of spaces 
            String spaces = new String(new char[spacesRequired]).replace('\0', ' ');
            //formatting element to the format with  decimal place 2
            String arrayElement=String.format("%.2f",A[i][j]);
            //Using ternary operator to calculate what to print for every third Element in your array
            System.out.print((j/2==1)?(spaces+arrayElement+"\n"):(spaces+arrayElement+"|"));
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
// Convert to String[][]
int cols = A[0].length;
String[][] cells = new String[A.length][];
for (int row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
    cells[row] = new String[cols];
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        cells[row][col] = String.format("%.2f", A[row][col]);
}

// Compute widths
int[] widths = new int[cols];
for (int row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        widths[col] = Math.max(widths[col], cells[row][col].length());
}

// Print
for (int row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        System.out.printf("%" + widths[col] + "s%s",
                          cells[row][col],
                          col == cols - 1 ? "\n" : " | ");
}
```

**Result:**

```
   3.15 |   96.10 |   77.12
 608.12 |   -5.15 |  -36.10
-753.56 | 6000.16 | -155.54
```